# How to generate Hibernate Annotated Entity classes with associations from Tables

Tags: database-design, eclipse-plugin, entity-relationship, hibernate-mapping, model-associations

I know plugins are available to generate hibernate pojos and mapping configuration xml file in eclipse. As hibernate with aanotations are now used more ofter than hibernate xml files, I wonder how do we generate Entity classes with proper associations (OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany etc) for Tables in dmd file which could save a lot of deveoplment effort with 100% accuracy.
As we can use dmd files to generate all database scripts with proper constraint/index etc creation. I wish there is a way to generate Entity classes as well.

--EDIT--

As I didnt find a solution to generate annotated enities from dmd file, so thought of generating tables from dmd file and then to use hibernate tool plugin to generate Entity classes atleast.

I could generate tables from dmd files. Now using Hibernate tool plugin in eclipse(Juno) to generate Entities following nicely written steps in

```
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/ and 
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse-ide/
```

I am getting `An internal error occurred during: "Fetching children of Database".` exception on click of `Hibernate code generation --> Run`

Detailed exception trace is like below. Can someoone tell me how to fix this error and generate files.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.OracleMetaDataDialect.getTables(OracleMetaDataDialect.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.processTables(JDBCReader.java:476)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```